# Remove rows and adjust number

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to remove objects from a list where a certain property value are identical to the previous/next objects property value. If an object are found I need to update the nested objects value.

**Example:**

```
Level | Text
1     | General
2     | Equipment  
3     | Field Staff  
2     | Scheduling  
3     | Scheduling
4     | Deadlines
4     | Windows
1     | Specialities
```

In the example above I want to remove the second **Scheduling** and change the **Deadlines** Level to **3** as well as the **Windows** to **3**.

I tried to look a head and compare with the next object in the list and also keep a counter but it didnt work.

```
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count(); i++)
{
    if (i <= notes.Count() - 1)
    {
        var currentRow = notes.ElementAt(i);
        var nextRow = notes.ElementAt(i + 1);

        if (currentRow.Text.Equals(nextRow.Text))
        {
            notes.Remove(nextRow);
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            notes.ElementAt(i).Level = notes.ElementAt(i).Level - counter;
            counter = 0;
        }                        
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @auburg Added my attempt

Comment: IMHO, use a `List<Work>` or some other class name (with props) to hold what you need. So you want to remove duplicate strings? Please show how this list is constructed?

Comment: Do you always want to set the following two items (Deadlines and Windows) to a lower level value when you find a duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `Linq`:

1 - Get distinct lines

```
var distinctList = notes
    .GroupBy(p => p.Text)
    .Select(v => v.First());
```

2 - get deleted level

```
IEnumerable<int> deletedLevel = notes
    .Except(distinctList)
    .Select(l => l.Level);
```

3 - update your distinct list

```
foreach(int level in deletedLevel)
{
    distinctList
        .Where(l => l.Level >= level + 1)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(item => { item.Level -= 1; });
}
```

**Result** :

```
Level | Text
1     | General
2     | Equipment  
3     | Field Staff  
2     | Scheduling  
3     | Deadlines
3     | Windows
1     | Specialities
```

i hope that will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = notesList.GroupBy(x => x.Text)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(y => y.Key)
            .Select(y => new { Element = y, Index = Array.FindIndex<Notes>(notesList.ToArray(), t => t.Text ==y)  })
            .ToList();

        var filteredList = new List<Notes>();

        foreach (var duplicate in query)
        {
            filteredList = notesList.Where((n, index) => index < duplicate.Index + 1).ToList();

            var newElems = notesList.Where((n, index) => index > duplicate.Index + 1).Select(t =>
                new Notes {Level = t.Level == 1 ? 1 : t.Level - 1, Text = t.Text});

            filteredList.AddRange(newElems);
        }
```

Comment: There can be any number of rows after the duplicates

Comment: In your example you only mention Deadlines and Windows (2 items) being modified?